# Can my problem be done in Python? Is so, How?

Tags: python

I need to be able to input two partially known factors each at 15 decimal places exactly and the product answer at 29 decimal places exactly. The beginning numbers (0.199848... and 4.97438...) of the two factors must remain unchanged during the program run. The zero's in each factor are what Python must work with and "numerically change". This "numerical change", when the factors are multiplied, must yield the product ‭0.99412293432154732337566954206 to 29 decimals and no less in order to match my product input. I would like to know what the final factors are along with the matching product once Python gets finished running.

Example:

My Input 
Factor 1     0.199848000000000 ‭ 
Factor 2     4.974380000000000 
Product      ‭0.99412293432154732337566954206

Output: 
What the output should hopefully be 0.199848442087413 X 4.974384208042620 = ‭0.99412293432154732337566954206

So in conclusion, Python would find out what the factors must be to match my input of the known product ‭0.99412293432154732337566954206 that I gave it. I think Python might use a combination/permutation on the zero's until it finds a combination that yields the product I input.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Of course it is quite easy to write a Python program to solve your problem by "brute force", ie. testing all possible combinations of digits. However, taking into account that there are 19 zeros in your example, this would reguire testing 10^19 combinations. Probably requires more time than you're going to wait. So, this is wrong way.

Comment: If you show us how you've already tried and/or the resources you've read, then we can help work around your trials or work on your pre-existing efforts. This is the place you visit **after** you've given it your very best shot and still can't come any closer to a solution.

Comment: Dantechguy, I would try but am not sure where to even begin.

Comment: Let us get this straight: given one number, you want a function that calculates two factors that multiplied together result in the number you gave? If yes, do you realize that there are literally infinite combinations of two numbers that multiplied together result in the number you give?

Comment: Kist:  My way of helping this issue is the partially known numbers within each factor that are to be kept constant when the program runs and only up to 15 decimal places.  Therefore, there won't be an infinite amount of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers;

- You cannot use floating point numbers. Those only have about 17 decimal digits of precision, and the conversion from decimal to binary floating point is imprecise by nature.
- A good place to start would be the `decimal` module.

For example:

```
In [1]: import decimal as dm

In [2]: dm.getcontext().prec = 29

In [3]: factor1 = dm.Decimal('0.199848')
Out[3]: Decimal('0.199848')

In [4]: factor2 = dm.Decimal('4.97438')
Out[4]: Decimal('4.97438')

In [5]: desired = dm.Decimal('0.99412293432154732337566954206')
Out[5]: Decimal('0.99412293432154732337566954206')

In [6]: factor1*factor2 > desired
Out[6]: False
```

- As pointed out by Błotosmętek in the comments, the number of combinations is much too large to do a brute force search. So you have to to it another way.

Keep in mind that a product can be;

- smaller than the required result,
- equal to the required result or
- larger than the required result.

In the first case, one of the factors has to become larger. In the last case, one of the factors has to become smaller.

Since the second factor is the largest, I would start with `factor1`.
Append a 9 to the Decimal (the largest possible increase), and check if the product is larger than the target.

```
In [7]: new1 = dm.Decimal('0.1998489')
Out[7]: Decimal('0.1998489')

In [8]: new1*factor2 > desired
Out[8]: True
```

So this number is too large. The largest integer smaller than 9/2 is 4, so try that.

```
In [9]: new1 = dm.Decimal('0.1998484')
Out[9]: Decimal('0.1998484')

In [10]: new1*factor2 > desired
Out[10]: False
```

Now halve the distance between 0.1998489 and 0.1998484. and check again. You'll find that 
0.1998487 is too big, but 0.1998486 is not.

Now go on to the next digit of `factor1`, and so on until you've found the right number of digits for `factor1`.

Then do the same with `factor2`, but now also test for equality.

**Edit:** Concerning the time necessary for brute-force.

Multiplying two `Decimal`s and comparing it to a third takes around 119 ns on my machine. One might think that this is not too bad.

```
In [2]: from decimal import Decimal

In [3]: f1 = Decimal('0.199848')
Out[3]: Decimal('0.199848')

In [4]: f2 = Decimal('4.97438')
Out[4]: Decimal('4.97438')

In [6]: result = Decimal('0.99412293432154732337566954206')
Out[6]: Decimal('0.99412293432154732337566954206')

In [7]: %timeit f1*f2 == result
119 ns ± 0.0114 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

But consider the worst-case, we have to do 10^19 of those calculations. Let's see how long that takes:

```
In [9]: round(119e-9*1e19/3600/24/365.25, 0)
Out[9]: 37709
```

So examining the whole problem domain takes *at least* 38000 years.

Of course you could get lucky and find the correct result after a couple of tries. But don't count on that. Without prior knowledge of where to seek, you could reasonably expect to need to check through half of the problem domain. **That is roughly 19000 years**. Hence Błotosmętek's remark that a brute-force search is infeasable.

Comment: Roland Smith:  I wouldn't mind knowing how to do this through the "brute force" method. 
Any help on getting a "brute force" python program would be much appreciated.  I've been working on a predictive model for 25 years now and knowing this is the last step in completing what I feel will be a ground breaking discovery in predicting.  I'm limited in my programming knowledge and not getting any younger and would like to see this come to fruition before I die.  LOL

Comment: @Jackritter I'm sorry to say that brute force is not an option due to the huge number of combinations involved. See updated answer.

Comment: Roland:  Thank you for your "brute" honesty.  I am able to perform this by hand by changing each decimal place zero to a different number and multiplying the factors to see how close it compares to the desired product then moving down the line of zero's one after another but am unable to see some form of pattern or logic when using a completely different set of factors and product.  As I tell my daughter, "we are never quitters", so I'll just keep forging forward.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Jackritter This is why [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) is often used in cryptography. It is *very hard* to find shortcuts, (especially if the numbers are prime). The linked article has links to some general purpose methods for factorization. Maybe those can be of use to you. Good luck!

Comment: Roland:  Sorry for beating a dead horse so it's even more dead than before, but I was thinking of my above problem late last night. If there was a way to eliminate the obviously ridiculous combinations such as 0.199848000000001, 0.199848000000002, or even number combinations containing a sequence where there are 3 or 4 similar integers in a row such as 0.199848233359762 or 0.199848233335974 then that might greatly cut down on the possibilities and shorten the time.  I'm out of characters to type in this box.  Please see my next comment.

Comment: Roland:  Cont: I think this might work because in all my years of numerical research and data compiling I've noticed that to have 3 or 4 similar numbers side-by-side in one large number is uncommon.  Having 3 similar numbers side-by-side occurs about 1 in 100.  To have 4 similar numbers side-by-side occurs about 1 in 1000.  I'm not sure how much having a program that could eliminate such combinations would help but it could be significant.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Jackritter Please have a good look at my answer and try to understand my method. What it does is essentially *start with the biggest numbers* and repeatedly *halve* the remaining problem domain.  In the first step, we can thus get rid of  5·10¹⁸ possibilities. You just keep on halving the remaining problem domain until there is only one solution left. Note that I'm not a numerical expert, so if there is a principle error in my solution, let me know.

Comment: Roland:  Yes, sorry, I will take a closer look.  By the way, and this is my lack of programming knowledge showing, Is your above example a macro for Excel?  If so, is it a chug and plug?  And what I mean by that is, can I put this in Excel the way it is and have it work as a macro or is this just an example to get me started down a path?  Thanks again for everything.  Jack

Comment: It is Python code running in the [IPython](https://ipython.org/) environment. It is just to show the principle. Excel is OK for simple calculations, but if you want to do serious number crunching **do not** do it in excel! It uses IEEE 754 double precision numbers. That means you only get about 15 significant digits. See also [numeric precision in excel].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). Additionally, several math functions in excel are known to be buggy. It is also much harder to "read" an excel spreadsheet than a file of programming language code.

Comment: Roland:  Last time, I promise.  I'm working your code above and it's helping a lot.  I believe I have found a logical process in changing the numbers manually and using, well, human common sense. I do have one more request, If it's not too much trouble, I need code, like above, to figure the RSQ of a list of numbers that I would need to input.  I need the RSQ value to be shown at 29 decimal places. I am able to do this in Excel using =RSQ(M5:M981,L5:L981) to only 15 dec. places.  Any help is appreciated.  This would get me closer to finishing than I could imagine after 25 years. Thanks, Jack

Comment: You'll have to implement it  from the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample) using `Decimal` numbers.